# How to write and run more than one code in Python IDLE?

Tags: python

How do you get the code seen below to run in the IDLE? I am stuck in my course right now and I could not find an explanation.

I know how to run in IDLE just one "def" or code, pressing F5, write e.g.
`hash_string('udacity', 3)` in the shell, "Enter", result. In that code, with more than one code it will not work, of course

For a deeper understanding I want to run it in the [Python Online Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/), but I would like it to run in the IDLE as well as the online tutor.

I would also like to know why the input `print hashtable_get_bucket(table, "Zoe")`
results in: `>>> [['Bill', 17], ['Zoe', 14]]`. Why does `['Bill', 17]` appear in the list?

```
# Define a procedure, hashtable_get_bucket,
# that takes two inputs - a hashtable, and
# a keyword, and returns the bucket where the
# keyword could occur.

def hashtable_get_bucket(htable,keyword):
     return htable[hash_string(keyword,len(htable))]


def hash_string(keyword,buckets):
     out = 0
     for s in keyword:
        out = (out + ord(s)) % buckets
     return out

def make_hashtable(nbuckets):
     table = []
     for unused in range(0,nbuckets):
        table.append([])
     return table


#table = [[['Francis', 13], ['Ellis', 11]], [], [['Bill', 17],
#['Zoe', 14]], [['Coach', 4]], [['Louis', 29], ['Rochelle', 4], ['Nick', 2]]]

#print hashtable_get_bucket(table, "Zoe")
#>>> [['Bill', 17], ['Zoe', 14]]

#print hashtable_get_bucket(table, "Brick")
#>>> []

#print hashtable_get_bucket(table, "Lilith")
#>>> [['Louis', 29], ['Rochelle', 4], ['Nick', 2]]
```

Thanks for taking the time reading that post and for your suggestions, too!